# Save into file git fetch terminal output

Tags: bash, scripting, git

I have tried several ways to save into a log file 'git fetch output' from terminal, through a bash file but without success, like,

```
git fetch origin > output.log
```

or even adding output.log in the front of the bash script where i have 'git fetch origin'.

With command script is the only way i have to record all the info into a txt file through '>', but i would have to insert it manually and it stops when i try to use it inside of a bash file to let me introduce commands, dont know if there is a way to use a bash file to insert 'git fetch origin' command inside of script command.

This is a sample of how the output in terminal is after i execute 'git fetch origin' command,

```
Xserver$ git fetch origin > output.log
remote: Counting objects: 14, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Total 14 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (14/14), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/x/test
 * [new branch]      branch1    -> origin/branch1
 * [new branch]      branch2    -> origin/branch2
 * [new branch]      branch3    -> origin/branch3
 * [new branch]      branch4    -> origin/branch4
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
```

Is there a way to save this output to a txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like git prints the output to stderr, so you should use `>&`.

Example: `git fetch -v >& test.txt`

Answer (score 1):

There is a command called `script` which can be used to save the terminal output of any command. It could for example be invoked like this:

```
script -f output.log -c 'git fetch origin'
```

Unlike ordinary redirection the command will still see stdout and stderr connected to a pts device, so commands which use different formatting for file output and terminal output will still be producing all the terminal formatting sequences.

Additional with `script` the output will be send to both your terminal and to the specified log file. Whether to use `script` or ordinary redirection depends on your exact usage scenario.

The parameters in the above command have the following meaning:

- `-f` write output to the log file immediately when produced (by default output is buffered).
- `output.log` the file name to write output to (by default named `typescript`).
- `-c 'git fetch origin'` the command to invoke (by default a shell will be started).